# Neo4j, empty list in first unwind stop second unwind from executing

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc, opencypher

I have two unwinds, that create some relationships and nodes, but if the list for the first unwinds is empty, the second unwind doesn't execute.

How can I fix that?

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "
        UNWIND $POSTS as post
        RETURN post
    ",
    "
        MERGE (p:Post{id: post.id})

        WITH p, post
        UNWIND post.tags as value
        MERGE (t:Tag{tag: value})
        MERGE (t)-[:has_tag]->(p)

        WITH p, post
        UNWIND post.user_mentions as user_mention
        MERGE (u1:User{id: user_mention})
        MERGE (p)-[:mentions]->(u1)
    ",
    {batchSize: 500, params: {POSTS: $POSTS}, iterateList:true}
)
```

### Example results

##### Parameters, with non-empty tags

```json
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "tags": [1],
        "user_mentions": [123, 234],
    }
]
```

##### Graph created in database - Expected result

[image]

##### Parameters, with empty tags

```json
[
    {
        "id": 123,
        "tags": [],
        "user_mentions": [123, 234],
    }
]
```

##### Graph created in the database (Lacking 'mentions' relationships) - Unexpected result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, UNWIND produces rows and thus if the list is empty no rows are produced and the query doesn't continue.

You need to switch to `FOREACH` for this use case :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
    "
        UNWIND $POSTS as post
        RETURN post
    ",
    "
        MERGE (p:Post{id: post.id})
        WITH p, post
        FOREACH(value IN  post.tags |
          MERGE (t:Tag{tag: value})
          MERGE (t)-[:has_tag]->(p)
        )
        WITH p, post
        FOREACH(user_mention IN post.user_mentions |
          MERGE (u1:User{id: user_mention})
          MERGE (p)-[:mentions]->(u1)
        )
    ",
    {batchSize: 500, params: {POSTS: $POSTS}, iterateList:true}
)
```